# Using JQuery to animate size of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am an amateur in Jquery but am so close to getting what I am looking for. I am trying to have a containing div animate to a larger height when an object is clicked. I am using the following code:

```
<div id="sliderone">
 <div id="nav">
  <div id="navone" style="text-align: center;">This is a clickable title</div>
 </div>

 <div id="ourteam">
  <div id="title"></div>
 </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#navone').click(function(){
   $('#title').html("<img src='http://placehold.it/350x550' alt='' />");
        $('.post-8 .content-container').animate({height: '950'});
   });  
</script>

#navone {
   padding:20px 20px;
   cursor:pointer; 
}

#title {
   width:350px;
   margin:0 auto;
}

#sliderone {
   height:50px;
   background-color:#777777;
   position: absolute;
   margin-top: -500px;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -175px;
}
```

`#sliderone` has to be absolutely positioned and so when I try to animate `.post-8 .content-container` it makes the top longer in comparison instead of making the bottom longer to contain the new content. Can I either animate the negative margin smaller or animate the bottom of the `.post-8 .content-container`?

Thank you for any help. I have worked hard on this and just can't quite figure out this last problem.

Here is the actual page to see.

http://s416809079.onlinehome.us/wp-login
login:stackoverflow
password:stackoverflow

Comment: look here http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp

Comment: What about using `slideDown` from the jQuery library?

Comment: You're using a class selector with jQuery, but those classes aren't present in the html. Your selector isn't going to pick anything up, and therefore won't animate anything.

Comment: where is ` $('.post-8 .content-container')` in html?

Comment: sorry. I made that confusing. (.post-8 .content-container) is the containing WordPress post.

Comment: See this, http://jsfiddle.net/82kHV/13/ I've added a mock `content-container` for testing.

Comment: Added more information in answer below with links to jQuery documentation on sliding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have this situation --> http://jsfiddle.net/z7M2Y/15/ . If that is the case you need to animate too the `height` for `#sliderone`:

```
$('#sliderone').animate({height: '225px'});/*The value you calculate*/
```

Check this demo **http://jsfiddle.net/z7M2Y/26/**

Comment: this is close to working, however (.post-8 .content-container) doesn't actually contain #sliderone so I am using a negative top margin to place it in front of it. So I don't need to make #sliderone larger but change the negative margin to create more space at the bottom. However- 

 $('#sliderone').animate({margin-top: '-225px'}); 

doesn't seem to be valid.

Comment: Thank you. I realize that, and I think I made it confusing. I created a login for you to view it yourself. I added it above. Thanks!

Comment: @natehoward How can i access the place you are talking about??? is a mess link to a web . Chek the fiddle with margintop working Try with marginTop instead of margin-top

Comment: the margintop example worked perfectly! Thank you so much! One other quick question - what do I need to add to have it reverse when clicked again?

Comment: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/beginner-function-toggle-deprecated-what-to-use-instead

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using some of jQuery's `slideDown`, `slideUp` or `slideToggle` methods. Since you are specifically looking to slide the container I imagine this might be more specific to your needs.

See this example based on what you have above: http://jsfiddle.net/82kHV/13/

Also links to jQuery methods:
http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/sliding/

You will set the element's height you want in your `CSS`. jQuery will interpolate and animated from 0 to this defined value in `slideDown` and the reverse in `slideUp`. `slideToggle` will take initial state of the element and do the opposite or toggle.

Comment: the problem that I realized is that (.post-8 .content-container) doesn't actual contain #sliderone. I am using a negative top margin to place it in front of it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly but regardless of the location of the `content-container` the `slideToggle` method should work the same.